# Configuring Pycharm to use Python 1.5.2+

Tags: python, pycharm, gsm, modem, gprs

I have to write an application for a GSM Modem from Telit that uses Python 1.5.2+

I have been using PyCharm CE only as an editor for my code but debugging and testing my code directly on modem hardware.

I've tried to configure my project to use Python 1.5.2+ and PyCharm calls it as "Unknown" as seen below:

[image: PyCharm Python 1.5.2+ configuration]

I also tried use Python Console but PyCharm doesn't support it.

I don't have enough experience with PyCharm, so I only want to confirm that it doesn't support Python 1.5.2+ or I'm doing something wrong. In last case, how can I configure it to use Python 1.5.2+?

Comment: Just wow.  I hope someone is paying you to do that.  :)

Comment: Yes, I'm being paid @wim

Comment: Did you use this installer, right? https://www.python.org/ftp/python/win32/py152.exe

Comment: No, I didn't @Hackerman It's from Telit. I'll try the one you've suggested.

Comment: @Hackerman Unfortunately the same "problem".

Comment: But are you sure that it is not supported? Did you try writing a basic script or something

Comment: @Hackerman When I try to run the script it returns "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" on line 38 of the file PyCharm file called pydevd.py.

Comment: That's maybe because in that line you are using an instruction not supported on that version of python...can you do a simple "hello world" to see if the script runs?

Comment: Hello World runs! But debug returns the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eldest Python, which PyCharm [supports](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/supported-languages.html), is 2.4.